# Is this Siegel's formula correct?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In the paper  [*Zum Beweise des Starkschen Satzes*](https://eudml.org/doc/141914) Siegel considers the function

$$L_q(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{q}{n}\right)n^{-s},$$

where $q$ is a discriminant of a quadratic number field and the character is the Kronecker symbol. Then he writes that "according to Dirichlet" we have, in case $G>0$,

$$L_G(1)=2G^{-1/2}h_G\log \varepsilon_G,$$

where $h_G$ is the corresponding class number and $\varepsilon_G$ the fundamental unit.

However, according to the book [Zetafunktionen und quadratische Körper](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61829-1) the formula reads

$$h_G=\frac{G^{1/2}}{\log \varepsilon_G}L_G(1).$$

Which one is correct? Am I making some mistake?

Comment: you mean where does the factor of two in the first formula come from?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, that is the problem.

Comment: Dirichlet's class number formula is quoted with this factor of two in several other sources, for example [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374077?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Maybe it would be wiser to read Dirichlet's proof itself.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Siegel is always right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dirichlet proved his class number formula for quadratic forms; in particular he was working with class numbers $h^+$ in the strict sense, and his unit $\varepsilon$ was the fundamental solution of the Pell equation $t^2 - Du^2 = 1$, not the fundamental unit $\eta$ of the corresponding number field. The relation
$$ \eta^{2h} = \varepsilon^{h^+} $$ 
encodes the two cases

- $\varepsilon = \eta$, $h^+ = 2h$
- $\varepsilon = \eta^2$, $h^+ = h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!